# Fsharp intellisense support failing in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, intellisense, f#-3.0

I have an Fsharp fsx file that includes some external libraries. First this worked well. But recently, intelli sense support and error checking is completely failing using VS2012 update 3. I have PostSharp en ReSharper installed as well.

Any clues about what is going on. I have posted on Microsoft forums and filed bug reports, however, no response;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved similar issues in the past:

- Make sure the #r directives are ordered according to the dependencies
  of the libraries on each other.
- Do not use the #I directive; instead, write the path in each #r directive.

Comment: The problem with failing IntelliSense when using the #I directive seems to be resolved in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to revoke my previous comment re. "Intellisense working with #I directive in VS 2013". It still is not consistently working -- sooner or later, Intellisense will fail when using the #I directive in a script. So I suggest always using only the #r directive, but never the #I directive in Visual Studio.